# Django HTML snippet for a model

Tags: django

I am new to Django and I am trying to find out how can I associate a HTML snippet with a model.

My HTML snippet is just a div. I want to reuse that div (you can think of it like a thumbnail)

Situation is like this: In my main page I want to show x objects and in my search page I want to show more objects. But the representation is the same.

I can write in the mainpage.html and searchpage.html the desired way of transforming the model object into a div but I am not sure what is the best way to reuse that transform?

I can add a function to my model which returns a HTML div, then I can call it from mainpage and searchpage templates. But that will couple the model and representation, which I believe is not a very nice thing to do.

If I am not mistaken [inclusion_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)s are the way to go but in which file should I keep the function definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you rightly say, you don't want html in your models, it's goes against the MVC pattern.

[Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/) are for storing data. [Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/) are for selecting the data to present whilst [Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/) are used for the actual presentation of data. (See this note on [django's interpretation of MVC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names)).

To answer your question, you need a template (or even a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/)), to represent your model, say `model_block.html`. Something like

```
{% if obj %}
    <div id=obj.id>
        {{ obj.name }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Then include your template in your `mainpage.html` like

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {% include 'model_block.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can do the same thing in your `searchpage.html`, passing a different `object_list` variable from your view.